# error while updating date datatype via C# and SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, datepicker

**(Sorry for the bad english )**

Hey , i got problem when im trying to update a Date datatype .

that's my SQL query

```
UPDATE       Employees
SET                BirthDateEmp = '04/11/2012'
WHERE        (IdEmp = 1)
```

So i set day = 4 ,month = 11 and year 2012

but when i check my table it switch between the day and the month so now the day 11 and the is month 4.

and i if try to set this date '13/10/2012' (day - 13 month - 10 year -2012) 
i got error because its trying to put : day-10 month-13 , and there's not month 13 so i get error

why its happening ?

Comment: Your sql server is running in en-US culture, so it's parsing date as `m/dd/yyyy`

Comment: how can i change it ?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SQL server is expecting US format dates (mm/dd/yyyy). You need to let us know what database and os you are using.

Comment: im using windows 7 (english) and my SQL server is built on C#.
but my own computer date is DD/MM/YYYY

and im guss i need to convert the SQL server to this (DD/MM/YYYY)

Comment: Also i want to edit that when im show the table data i see the date written in DD/MM/YYYY (just like in my own computer)

Answer (score 0):

The localisation settings on your application and database are incompatible with each other.

You appear to have (and want) UK date formats (DD/MM/YYYY) in your application, but US date formats (MM/DD/YYYY) in your database.

You could change your database to store dates in a neutral format and then update your application to take local dates and convert them to this neutral format before storing in the database and from it when displaying them.

You should also be storing dates in Date (or DateTime) columns, not as strings.

Comment: i serach in google and didnt find good answer for how to change database to store in UTC ..

Comment: @user2120874 - sorry, I used UTC as shorthand. I'll update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the date format you're using is ambiguous and the culture on the server is not the one you're expecting.

Ideally you want to work with typed parameters and never deal with dates as strings.

If you do have to use a string I've found the following format to be most consistently successful: yyyy-MM-dd

Comment: i used date datatype and datetimepicker

Comment: @user2120874 sure, but how did you build the query?

Answer (score -1):

You can change the format of Date datatype by code and check the query

```
UPDATE       Employees
SET                BirthDateEmp = '11/04/2012'
WHERE        (IdEmp = 1)
```

that will update your table because the default format for date datatype is (MM/dd/yyyy) in SQL so follow this.

Comment: Bad advice because it just changes one assumption for another that will not be generically applicable